# Git Won't Show Changes I Made to a File

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I'm trying to learn how to use github, so I'm following along with this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RGOj5yH7evk&t=186s
I made a new repository and filled it with a file called README.md. You can see it here: https://github.com/suzm10/beginner-repo
But, when I make changes to the file in visual studios, the git status command doesn't show that I made any changes and so I can't commit them.
Here's what it looks like:
[visual studios screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlBMW.png)

Comment: You didn't save your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you save the file?
If there is a "white dot" right next to the filename in the tab then the file is not saved to disk.